# Formatting file using awk

Tags: awk

I am attempting to format two pieces of data from my awk script. Here is a piece of my raw data

```
Mike:James:314849866:mjames69@asu.edu:5059358554:NM:8830:Johnson:Rd:Albuquerque:87122
```

There are a total of nine lines like this. I have formatted it in this manner

```
Mike James, 314849866
8830 Johnson Rd
Albuquerque, NM 87122
mjames69@asu.edu
5059358554
```

using this code:

```
cat rawadd | awk -F:  ' NR == 1,NR == 9 {print $1 " " $2 ", " $3 "\n" $7 " " $8 " " $9 "\n" $10 ", " $6 " " $11 "\n" $4 "\n" $5
```

I would like to format the phone number, the fifth line like (505)935-8554. So I created a new variable $tel, and replaced it with the $5 variable that I extracted from the rawadd file.

Here is what that new code looks like:

```
tel=`"(${5:0:3}) ${5:3:3}-${5:6:4}"`


cat rawadd | awk -F:  ' NR == 1,NR == 9 {print $1 " " $2 ", " $3 "\n" $7 " " $8 " " $9 "\n" $10 ", " $6 " " $11 "\n" $4 "\n" $tel "\n"}';
```

But my output is coming out like this

```
Mike James, 314849866
8830 Johnson Rd
Albuquerque, NM 87122
mjames69@asu.edu
Mike:James:314849866:mjames69@asu.edu:5059358554:NM:8830:Johnson:Rd:Albuquerque:87122
```

On the fifth line it just prints the actual line input, and not the formatted telephone number. I was hoping that I might add the formatting directly into the awk command, but cannot figure out a way. I would also like to format the Id number on the first line to be 314-84-9866. Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: your `$tel` variable is not visible in `awk`, within single quotes bash variables are not substituted.  Even it was visible the way you coded doesn't work in `awk`.  Instead you have to use `"(" substr($5,1,3) ")" .. etc` in the `awk` script.

Comment: Google UUOC and then consider what value `cat rawadd` is adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to [@karakfas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522059/1745001) but will work in any awk, uses a choice of OFS that I think better represents your real output fields, and will only process the first 9 input lines, like in your original script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS=", " }
{
    print $1 " " $2, substr($3,1,3) "-" substr($3,4,2) "-" substr($3,6)
    print $7 " " $8 " " $9
    print $10, $6 " " $11
    print $4
    print "(" substr($5,1,3) ")" substr($5,4,3) "-" substr($5,7)
}
NR==9 { exit }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Mike James, 314-84-9866
8830 Johnson Rd
Albuquerque, NM 87122
mjames69@asu.edu
(505)935-8554
```

The first problem you were having with your `tel` variable is that when you write:

```
tel=7
awk '{print $tel}'
```

you actually have 2 completely different variables, a shell variable named `tel` created by `tel=7` in the shell script, and an awk variable also named `tel` created by `print $tel` in the awk script and completely unrelated to the shell variable of the same name.

The second problem you were having is that to access the contents of an awk variable you just use the variable name, just like you would in C, you do not prepend it with a `$` like you would in shell.

The third problem you were having is that since the awk variable `tel` is unset it gets the value zero-or-null (all awk variables are of type numeric-string - google that) and so when you use `$tel` that's the same as if you said `$0` whose contents are the entire input line (record).

All of those together are why you were getting the input line reproduced in your output.

The syntax to do what you were trying to do would be:

```
tel=7
awk -v tel="$tel" '{print tel}'
```

where `-v tel="$tel"` is initializing an awk variable named `tel` with the contents of the shell variable also named `tel`. More clearly:

```
shelltel=7
awk -v awktel="$shelltel" '{print awktel}'
```

It's very important to understand that **awk is not shell** - it's a completely separate tool with it's own scope and a language whose syntax is much more similar to C than to shell.

Comment: Thank you Ed, I will go this route!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution with `gawk`,

```
awk -F: '{
          print $1, $2 ",", gensub(/(...)(..)(....)/,"\\1-\\2-\\3",1,$3);
          print $7, $8, $9; 
          print $10 ",", $6, $11; 
          print $4
          print gensub(/(...)(...)(....)/,"(\\1)\\2-\\3",1,$5)
         }' file
```

will give

```
Mike James, 314-84-9866
8830 Johnson Rd
Albuquerque, NM 87122 
mjames69@asu.edu
(505)935-8554
```

your `NR==1 ...` didn't make any sense to me.  Perhaps you have some reason but need to explain.

Comment: NR ==1, NR ==9  is reading in lines one - nine of the file and formatting them based on the selections I have made. Everything works fine, except for the part with formatting the telephone number and ID. I would like to try and work out the command that I have, but It appears that I cannot add new variables into this awk command, so I may need to utilize your method after all. Unless my comment makes any sense to you. Thank you

Comment: @EdMorton Morton, If you look at my fist command, Iuse  just the "$5" to display the phone number. I was hoping to do all of my code as efficient as possible, so I was hoping that I could reformat the telephone number in the variable "$tel" which I would then insert into my awk command. I am realizing that this would not be the the best method. Karakfa seems to have provided the most efficient use of awk for my purpose.